# How to make a header bar fold over the webpage css

Tags: html, css, effect

Can someone please tell me the CSS code or point me to a tutorial on how to achieve this effect see all the time.
Here is a image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Note: I know how to position with absolute I just need to know how they pull the effect off.

Comment: Is this a question about the positioning or about the "ribbon banner effect"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the ribbon is the issue, then use borders on an empty (*0-size*) element (*which you can add with `:after` pseudo-element*)..

**Html**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="ribbon"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    background-color:#77c;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
#ribbon{
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    right:-20px;
    top:50px;
    background-color:#999;
}
#ribbon:after{
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;

    border-color: transparent transparent #666 #666;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px 10px;

    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:-10px;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zJPhy/

Comment: thank you Gaby that's perfect can you give me a example of a left sided one too please.

Comment: @JohnFloyd, see http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zJPhy/2/ just need to re-order the border colors and position it correctly..

Answer (score 1):

This could be positioned relatively, or absolutely - it could be done either way:

```
#item {
    position: relative;
    right: -10px; /* moves it 10px to the right */
}
```

Or absolutely:

```
#item {
    position: absolute:
    top: 20px; /* 20px from the top */
    right: -20px; /* 20px off the right edge */
}
```

Note that absolutely positioned elements will be positioned according to the viewport if they have no positioned ancestors.

The folded portion can be accomplished using borders on the pseudo-element `:before` or `:after`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MaepP/2/